# Trying to related tables columns and sums with Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Ok.
I have three tables

```
products
--product_id
--product_name
--product_type_id
--price15
--price23
--description
--bonus_points
--image

productTypes
--product_type_id
--product_type_name

productQuantities
--id
--product_id
--warehouse_id
--quantity
```

Products are placed in different warehouses so I have to keep tracks of its numbers

And has relationships are like this

```
class Product extends Model 
{
    public function productType() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProductType','product_type_id','product_type_id');
    }

    public function productQuantities() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductQuantity','product_id','product_id');
    }
}
```

What I want to get is all columns from products and product type name from productType, sum of quantity from productQuantities, so I can perform search on those column values later on with where().

How can I get these columns with Eloquent?

I know I could get them with raw SQL commands but I need to do this way for compatibility reasons.
I tried this way before I ask the question.
But model relations just stopped working with no errors. Values just got emptied out from the other parts of the page.

```
        $products = Product::selectRaw('products.*, productTypes.product_type_name, sum(product_quantities.quantity) as quantitySum')
                    ->leftjoin('productTypes','products.product_type_id','=','productTypes.product_type_id')
                    ->leftjoin('productQuantities','products.product_id','=','productQuantities.product_id')
                    ->where('products.product_id','like','%'.$searchID.'%')
                    ->where('product_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%')
                    ->where('product_type_name', 'like', '%'.$searchType.'%')
                    ->where(function($q) use ($searchPrice) {
                        $q->where('price15','like','%'.$searchPrice.'%')
                          ->orwhere('price23','like','%'.$searchPrice.'%');
                    })
                    ->where('points', 'like', '%'.$searchPoints.'%')
                    ->groupBy('products.product_id')
                    ->orderByRaw($query)
                    ->paginate($paginateBy);
```

Working version before this was simple.

```
Product::leftjoin('productTypes','products.product_type_id','=','productTypes.product_type_id')
                            ->select('products.*','productTypes.product_type_name')
                            ->where('products.product_id','like','%'.$searchID.'%')
                            ->where('product_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%')
                            ->where('product_type_name', 'like', '%'.$searchType.'%')
                            ->where(function($q) use ($searchPrice) {
                                $q->where('price15','like','%'.$searchPrice.'%')
                                  ->orwhere('price23','like','%'.$searchPrice.'%');
                            })
                            ->where('points', 'like', '%'.$searchPoints.'%')
                            ->orderByRaw($query)
                            ->paginate($paginateBy);
```

And I thought any kind of join methods doesn't seem to be working well with Eloquent relationship? But older one has leftjoin method as well.

Comment: When you say you can use "raw sql commands", do you mean you don't want to use an eloquent `select(DB::raw())` command?

Comment: @Andrew
oh I didn't try select(DB::raw()), but I did try selectRaw() with leftjoin(). But productQuantities collection somehow stopped getting the data on places like this.
foreach($products->productQuantities as pq)
    pq->quantity
endforeach

Comment: See if my answer below is helpful, if it's not working for you then adding the query you tried to your question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = Product::withsum('productQuantities','quantity')
            ->leftjoin('product_types','products.product_type_id','=','product_types.product_type_id')
```

Gives me the result that I wanted. And didn't break the other parts.

But I'm still confused why with() and withSum() didn't work together.
Is it because `products` belongs to `productTypes` maybe

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this (and am assuming you want to group on `product_type_name` but you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
$results = Product::with(['productType','productQuantities'])
                    ->select(DB::raw('products.*, 
                                    productType.product_type_name, 
                                    sum(productQuantities.quantity) as "QuantitySum"'))
                    ->groupBy('productType.product_type_name')
                    ->get();
```

OR

```
$results = DB::table('products')
               ->join('productType', 'productType.product_type_id', '=', 'products.product_type_id')
               ->join('productQuantities', 'productQuantities.product_id', '=', 'products.product_id') 
               ->select(DB::raw('products.*, 
                                 productType.product_type_name, 
                                 productType.product_type_name, 
                                 sum(productQuantities.quantity) as "QuantitySum"'))
                    ->groupBy('productType.product_type_name')
                    ->get();
```

Then you should be able to access the aggregated quantities using (in a loop if you wanted) `$results->QuantitySum`.

Comment: Gave me column not found error. 
product_type_name not found

Comment: @BaljinnyamOlkhonud I revised my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Then all other parts of my page stops working.
I avoided this way, so I don't mess with them. I can't get anything from eloquent's model relation.

Comment: I have updated the code again, I missed the `with()` statement my first time.

Comment: Even with with(), gives me column not found error.
And I also updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and [aggregating](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models). For example, you need to query products has product type name like "new product" and quantity greater than 1000:

```
Product::with("productType")
    ->whereHas("productType", function ($query) {
        $query->where("product_type_name", "like", "new product");
    })
    ->withCount(["productQuantities as quantity_count" => function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw("sum(quantity)");
    }])
    ->having("quantity_count", ">", 1000)
    ->get();
```

you can get through relationship

```
$product->productType->product_type_name
```

and attribute:

```
$product->quantity_count
```

Comment: I needed sum not count tho.
Can I change column name in withSum same way as withCount?

Comment: what laravel version you are using

Comment: I change the withCount callback to sum the quantity, in laravel 8 you can replace it with withSum('productQuantities', 'quantity')